# Posting form data from VB.NET to PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, forms

So I am trying to make a login form on my vb.net application that would connect in my mysql database via my php script. So I've set up a wampp server to test it out. Got my php code below

```
    <?php
if($_POST)
{
    if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $connect = mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","");
        if($connect)
        {
            $select = mysql_select_db("ktmf",$connect);
            if($select)
            {
                $user = mysql_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
                $pwd = mysql_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
                $GetRows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pwd'");
                $RowCount=mysql_num_rows($GetRows);
                if($RowCount>0)
                {
                    die("Correct !");
                }
                else
                {
                    die("Incorrect !");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                die("Unable to select database." . mysql_error());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            die("Unable connect to database." . mysql_error());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die("Access Denied!");
    }
}
else
{
    die("Access Denied!");
}
?>
```

and then I got my vb.net code there

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Public Class login


    Function AuthUser(ByVal AuthenticationPage As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
        Dim wc As New WebClient()
        wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        Dim Data As String = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(Username), WebUtility.UrlEncode(Password))
        Dim ResponseBytes() As Byte = wc.UploadData(AuthenticationPage, "POST", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data))
        Dim Response As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ResponseBytes)
        If Response.Contains("Correct") Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function



    Private Sub login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If AuthUser("http://127.0.0.1/login.php", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text) Then
            Me.Hide()
            works.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("You have provided invalid username or password. Unable to login.")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

So when I try to login with the Application I got the Error "You have provided invalid username or password. Unable to login." wich I specified incase of error.

I still dont know what I did wrong, But if someone could help me I'd apreciate.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not contain much information, so only generaly:

1) Check what actual response (if any) you get

2) If you do not get any response, check web server log to see, if the request make it there at all

3) Test your PHP script independently on VB.NET. E.g. Simple HTML form would do.

If you share with us your findings based on above, you may get more specific answers.